# How many outbound links on a page are too many?

Tags: seo, google-search

I've got a page that links out to a bunch of songs / tabs for beginner guitarists. In total, the page has about 400 outbound links which seems like a lot I know, however I can't really justify removing any of the links because I feel each one serves a purpose.

I'm asking this question because I got hit by Google Fred on March 9 and I'm still trying to recover. I know some blog posts say that you shouldn't go over 100 outbound links per page, others say you shouldn't go over 250, others say 500.

Just trying to get other webmasters' opinions on what you think about my outbound link scenario for that particular page? I've also got other pages like it that showcase a list of fingerstyle songs however this list of beginners songs is by far the biggest.

Comment: Personally... I'd aim for a number that my visitors will appreciate. I can't think of any good user experience websites with 100 outbound links on the same page, let alone 250, 500...

Comment: I recommend not looking like a link farm. However, you seem to indicating one page so in that regard, you should be safe. Still, there has to be a better way to present your content so there are not 400 links. If you were pinged by G then I would be looking in other areas for what else could be wrong.

Comment: Check out this page. http://searchengineland.com/googles-fred-update-hit-low-value-content-sites-aimed-revenue-helping-users-271165 It seems to fairly clear that this is a content quality mixed with advertising issue. See if this describes your site.

Comment: Well I have 400 links because for each song I have a link to the song on youtube, a link to the tab and a link to the guitar pro tab. Therefore for each song I have 3 links. Although I have 100 songs in total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've got a page that links out to a bunch of songs / tabs for beginner guitarists. In total, the page has about 400 outbound links which seems like a lot I know, however I can't really justify removing any of the links because I feel each one serves a purpose.

**Categorize everything**

Since you have 400 songs, I'm sure you can group them into categories. Perhaps group them by type of music. For example, maybe 100 songs are rap and 100 are rock, 100 are dance, and 100 are jazz. Then you can have 4 pages each with 100 songs of one genre.

If that doesn't break things down enough, maybe categorize them by artist.

But if you really want to break things down the easy way, sort the songs by the first letter of the song name. Then you'll have 26 separate pages, one for each letter.

There are so many ways you can divide up your songs but it is important that you do. I understand it requires the user to make one extra click but at the same time, he/she won't have to scroll through countless pages looking for a particular title.

Comment: So in general, you think that it would definitely benefit SEO to break it down into multiple pages? In total, I have over 100 songs (each song has 3 links attributed to it for the youtube link, and tab links). However on the page itself I broke it down into 2 sections: 1 section was for chord songs and 1 section was for tab songs. Do you think it would make sense to just make each section an individual page?

Comment: Yes. One page for chord songs, and one page for tab songs if tab is an actual music category.  Just don't make users scroll endlessly. Its best to categorize.